# Node clustering with Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Does anyone know if it is possible to do clustering in the way that vis.js supports it with cytoscape.js? Here are some examples:

https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/other/clusteringByZoom.html

https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/other/clustering.html

The basic idea is that a node can represent a cluster of child nodes and zooming or double clicking on the node will "explode" it to show all the children.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect using `cy.on('zoom')` with `cy.add()` and `cy.remove()`.  That sort of feature would not be included in the lib proper, because it breaks graph semantics.